# Codeigniter forcedownload is redirecting to browser instead of downloading file

Tags: codeigniter-3, force-download

I have some images and each image is having a link. When I click on image one popup will open and in that popup I am displaying data in table format. In that table there is a download link. When user click on the download link, file should be download.That was my requirement. Below is my controller function to open popup and display data in table.

```
public function viewCommunication()
{
$post_data = $this->input->post();
$c_id = $post_data['c_id'];
$m_id = $post_data['m_id'];
$this->db->where("(c_id IN($c_id) AND mentee_id IN ($m_id))");
$query = $this->db->get('upload_checklist');
$checklist_data =  $query->result();
$data['viewchecklist_data'] = json_decode(json_encode($checklist_data),TRUE);
$data4 = "";
$data4.='<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
   <thead>
      <tr>
       <th>Initial Meeting</th>
       </tr>
        </thead>
    <tbody>';
foreach($data['viewchecklist_data'] as $key=>$value){
$download_link = 'MyController/downloadFile($value['initial_meeting'])';
$data4.='<tr>
   <td><a href='.$download_link.'>'.$initial_meeting.'</a></td>
  </tr>';
   }
$data4.='</tbody> </table>';
echo $data4;
}
```

// Function to download

```
public function downloadFile($file_name)
    {
        $this->load->helper('download');
        $path = base_url().'upload/files/'.$file_name;
        force_download($file_name,$path);
    }
```

But When I click on download link , the download link is going to the browser url like http://localhost/project/mycontroller/downloadFile(filename.doc) like this. Where I am doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: http://localhost/project/mycontroller/downloadFile(filename)

change the link to 

http://localhost/project/mycontroller/downloadFile/filename

and check the documentation for uri in codeigniter 
https://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/uri.html

the format is  classname/method/parameter1/parameter2/...

Comment: Hi, thank you , I have already fixed this one by passing like below $download_link = base_url().'MyControllder/downloadFile/'.$m_id.'/'.$file_name.'';